# mongoose not added it in same object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have data in this structure:

```
{
    "_id": "5f212467b57c1e693fd89060",
    "location":
        {
            "coordinates": [-31.802758, 115.837737],
            "type": "Point"
        },
    "store": "Liberty Landsdale",
    "__v": 0,
    "getdata": [
        {
            "2020-07-30":
                {"95": "1.14"}
        },
        {
            "2020-07-30":
                {"91": "1.02"}
        }
    ]
}
```

However I want it to look like this

```
{
    "_id": "5f212467b57c1e693fd89060",
    "location": {
        "coordinates": [-31.802758, 115.837737],
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "store": "Liberty Landsdale",
    "__v": 0,
    "getdata": [
        {
            "2020-07-30":
                [
                 {"95": "1.14"},
                 {"91": "1.02"}
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I know the problem is the way I am inserting it into mongodb

```
mFuel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {'store': t, 'location': [{coordinates: [lat, long], type: "Point"}]},
    {$addToSet: {'getdata': {[d]: {[ftype]: p}}}}, {upsert: true}, 
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR when submitting round');
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

I have tried `$push` as well as `set` and `addToSet`

I am wondering what is the correct way to achieve what am trying to do?

Comment: Are you ok to change the format how you store it?

Comment: @Gibbs yes if their is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) with `$set` to achieve this:

```
let d = '2020-07-30';
let setKey = `getdata.$[elem].${d}`;
let arrayFiltersKey = `elem.${d}`;
let col = await mFuel.updateOne(
    {
        'store': t, 'location': [{coordinates: [lat, long], type: 'Point'}]
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            [setKey]: {[ftype]: p}
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {[arrayFiltersKey]: {$exists: true}},
        ]
    });
```

Note that this cannot work with `upsert` as the usage of `arrayFilters` with it throws an error.

Regardless this data structure strikes me as odd, I would recommend you change it to something that's easier to work with.

either:

```
"getdata": [
    {
        k: "2020-07-30",
        v: [{"95": "1.14"}]
    }
]
```

Or

```
"getdata": {
    "2020-07-30": [
        {"95": "1.14"}
    ]
}
```

-------------- edit -------------------

With the second structure:

```
let d = '2020-07-30';
let setKey = `getdata.${d}`;
let col = await mFuel.updateOne(
    {
        'store': t, 'location': [{coordinates: [lat, long], type: 'Point'}]
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            [setKey]: {[ftype]: p}
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    });
```

Comment: Hi Tom that was what I was trying to do was the bottom one.

Comment: @Thank you so very much - I did not know you could do things like this with mongoose.

Comment: I added it, just remember this will not "reset" a value in the array i.e if you want to "update" the "95" value. in that case you'll have to use `arrayFilters` again or change the structure to `{"getdata": {"2020-07-30": {"95": "1.14",  "96": "12"}}}` and then you can just use `$set`\

Comment: We only get the data supplied once a day - so we each date will have a new row.

Comment: Glad I could help